# what can be used to scrape data that is loaded using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I understand that javascript is a browser side scripting language. I have a page which i am trying to scrape. it has a table;i am being able to scrape all the table datas, except for one, which is loaded by javascript. its an odds comparison website with constantly changing odds. the odds are loaded using javascript.

What can i use instead of simple php dom to parse the javascript?

Comment: use the source of the data directly. ie if $.ajax(url) the get the url.

Comment: How do you scrape data on client side ?

Comment: I was using simple html dom to scrape data which worked fine for me, but there is one field which is generated by javascript. that is the problem. i want to scrape this field.

Answer (score 1):

(If you can install software to your server) you could use a "headless" browser ( a browser without user interface) like phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/) that returns the full website including the results of the parsed javascript and feed the result to your php script.